# How can I get the value of a specific excel cell in asp.net in a string or integer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, dataset

I have created a dataset from a excel file. The excel sheet has 2 tabs: Employee and Comment. The Employee tabs has a logo merge cells and name of the company. The header off all the data begins on row 6 column A. I want to read all header of the table.

So I tried this:

```
var foo = (string)dataset.Tables[0].Rows[5][0];
```

The error message i get is: There is no row at position 5, but i'm pretty sure it is in de excel sheet.

I have created a Dataset with:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    System.Data.DataTable dbSchema = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    if (dbSchema == null || dbSchema.Rows.Count < 1)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Error: Could not determine the name of the first worksheet.");
                    }
                    string firstSheetName = dbSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    var aQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + firstSheetName + "]";
                    using (OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(aQuery, connection))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Command))
                        {
                            DataSet Data = new DataSet();
                            DataAdapter.Fill(Data);
                            return Data;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: "There is no row at position 5, but i'm pretty sure it is." How sure? Have you verified it in the debugger?

Comment: Attach dataset screenshots ...

Comment: No im net sure it is in de dataset but in the excelsheet.

Comment: Is the dataset creation the right way?